# Files (specifically PSD and Image files) Disappearing from Computer

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, google-drive, psd

I am using Google Drive to back up specific folders and their files from my computer. I am specifically using this to back up my art files, so PSD's and the outputs (jpgs and pngs). I have been completely losing these files at seemingly random points. Other filetypes and subfolders do not seem to be affected by this. They're not in any of the recommended backup locations, they are completely gone from my computer. They are also not on my Google Drive. So, I have lost hours and hours of work. It seems to me that this must have something to do with Google Drive, and I have no idea what's happening. The point of using Google Drive is to ensure that I DON'T lose files. Does anyone have any experience with anything similar to this? It doesn't seem like there's any way to recover my lost files (PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong!) but is there any way to actually back up my files with Google Drive or know what's happening?

It's possible that this problem began before setting up Google Drive, but I honestly don't remember at this point.

I'm using Windows 10, if that helps.

Comment: Possibly they are marked as hidden files, go to folder options in control panel and un-hide hidden files.

Comment: @Moab I have checked this prior to posting, no luck.

Comment: Were all the missing on your Google drive? Have you done a search for a known file name? (preferably with a proper search utility)? If yes, can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1421129/edit) so we don't go over already covered ground?